KCS interface register offset
I am working on a bare-minimal KCS driver implementation in UEFI shell.
The IPMI spec has detailed description on how to use the different register sets to enable communication between UEFI and BMC.
However, I am not able to understand the offset manipulation of important 4 registers.
From IPMI spec:

From SMBIOS table (smbiosview command in UEFI shell), I can see KCS interface is enabled and the base address as 0xCA3 (last bit indicating this is in IO space - hence, actual base address is 0xCA2 - which is same as mentioned in IPMI spec).
If there are 4 registers, I would expect the offsets as base+0, base+1, base+2 and base+3. However, the spec has both Status and Command as base+1; and Data_out and Data_In as base+0.
Can somebody explain please?
How do I read from status register and write into command register if they share the same offset?
